# Perl6: NCurses and mouse events

Tags: mouseevent, ncurses, raku

I do not succeed in getting returned a mouse event from `getmouse`. Are there errors in my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use NCurses;

my $win = initscr;
raw();
keypad( $win, True );
my Array[int32] $old;
mousemask( ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS +| REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION, $old ) or die;

loop {
    my $key = getch();
    if $key == KEY_MOUSE {
        my NCurses::MEVENT $event;
        my $ok = getmouse( $event );
        endwin;
        say "ok:    ", $ok.perl;    # -1
        say "event: ", $event.perl; # NCurses::MEVENT
        exit;
    }
}
```

[NCurses](https://github.com/azawawi/perl6-ncurses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less-than-awesome silent failure is masking the fact that you're passing a type object into getmouse().  I only found it by substituting `$event.perl` with `$event.x` on line 18 as an information fishing expedition.  Doing that produces;

```
user@Ubuntu-iMac:~$ ./getmouse.p6
ok:    -1
Invocant requires an instance of type NCurses::MEVENT, but a type object was passed.  Did you forget a .new?
  in block  at ./getmouse.p6 line 17
```

...which is just a little more informative.

I'm sure you get it now but, for the record, you typed the $event variable but didn't assign any value to it, so it gets the type object which according to the [Perl6 class tutorial](http://doc.perl6.org/language/classtut) is an undefined, "empty instance" of the type.
By simply substituting `my $event = NCurses::MEVENT.new;` for `my NCurses::MEVENT $event;` on line 13, one gets;

```
user@Ubuntu-iMac:~$ ./getmouse.p6
ok:    0
event: NCurses::MEVENT.new(id => 0, x => 70, y => 26, z => 0, bstate => 128)
```

... and all is well with the world.

Comment: Yes - I was finding the solution and drafting my answer while that happened.  Many thanks for accepting mine despite finding it yourself - I'm glad you found it yourself - I just wish you had done so half an hour later.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## The usual idiom

If you have to write a type's name as part of a variable declaration you might as well write it as the variable's type constraint and use `.= new` rather than using either Marty's or your solution:

```
my NCurses::MEVENT $event .= new
```

Marty's solution:

```
my $event = NCurses::MEVENT.new
```

works because `$event` now contains what the `getevent($event)` call needs it to contain, namely a new NCurses::MEVENT object. But it passes up an easy opportunity to add type-checking.

Your solution:

```
my NCurses::MEVENT $event = NCurses::MEVENT.new
```

means the same as the usual idiom for this situation but isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

## What went wrong

The [line of code that glues the Perl 6 `getmouse` call to the underlying native NCurses library](https://github.com/azawawi/perl6-ncurses/blob/master/lib/NCurses.pm6#L796) starts:

```
sub getmouse(MEVENT) ...
```

This tells Perl 6 that getmouse needs one argument of type `NCurses::MEVENT`.

Marty's solution worked. They didn't tell Perl 6 what type of value `$event` should contain. But they put the right value in it anyway so the lack of type-checking didn't matter.

Your original solution enabled useful type-checking. It told Perl 6 to make sure that `$event` only ever contained an object of type `NCurses::MEVENT`. Unfortunately you didn't explicitly initialize the variable so it contained...

Hang on. What did it contain? Shouldn't Perl 6 have made sure that there was an `NCurses::MEVENT` object in `$event` anyway?

In fact it did! But rather than putting an *ordinary* new `NCurses::MEVENT` object in there Perl 6 put an old `NCurses::MEVENT` **type** object in there as a placeholder. Among other things, Type objects represent the notion of an uninitialized object. (A bit like "undef" in Perl 5.)

This mechanism normally works well for surfacing errors like forgetting to suitably initialize a variable. But not in this case. So what went wrong?

Back to the `getmouse` declaration. It should have been:

```
sub getmouse(MEVENT:D) ...
```

The `:D` "type smiley" would tell Perl 6 that the argument has to be *defined*, ie that an *uninitialized* `NCurses::MEVENT` isn't good enough. With this smiley you'd have gotten an appropriate error rather than silence.

Comment: Raiph - I think you're spot on with the suggested `sub getmouse(MEVENT:D)` signature and with your earlier suggestion of using `.= new` __when type checking is wanted.__  I disagree with your implication that type checking *should* be used everywhere.  Short, little programs where there's almost no risk of confusion over types and no prospect of material performance gain don't need all the checks and constraints, do they?  Cant we ride on the wild side occasionally?  ;-)

Comment: I wasn't implying explicit type checking should be used everywhere. A coder may not care about type constraints for many scripts. But the alternative I listed does the same job as your solution, does no harm, is the usual idiom, may catch type errors anyway, may speed code up even though it doesn't matter, and establishes the right coding pattern for when a coder *does* care about speed or catching type errors. TIMTOWTDIBSCINABTE. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the missing part:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use NCurses;

my $win = initscr;
raw();
keypad( $win, True );
my Array[int32] $old;
mousemask( ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS +| REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION, $old ) or die;

loop {
    my $key = getch();
    if $key == KEY_MOUSE {
        my NCurses::MEVENT $event = NCurses::MEVENT.new;
        my $ok = getmouse( $event );
        endwin;
        say "ok:    ", $ok.perl;
        say "event: ", $event.perl;
        exit;
    }
}
```